# JavaScript: What will break, and what will break it?

Tags: javascript, resources, unobtrusive-javascript

```
Potentially dangerous code below, line 2
Repeat: POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS CODE BELOW
```

```
var history = ""; 
for (start = 3; start = 1000; start += 1){
  if(start % 5 == 0 || start % 3 == 0) 
    history += start + " "; }
```

Okay, this is the tenth time I've put JavaScript code in that's frozen my browser.  It's putting my computer in shock.  Are these panic attacks going to destroy her heart?  Where can I learn about all the crap that might break my computer as I continue to learn and practice JavaScript?  I'm looking for an exhaustive list, only.

Comment: If you managed to break your computer using Javascript, I'll promise to buy you a new one.

Comment: Your loop never terminates, which is why it locks your browser. Did you mean `for(start = 3; start < 1000; start += 1)`?

Comment: This is impossible to answer. You learn from your mistakes. Open task manager and kill the process. Use your debugger to find where you've screwed up.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to look for resources.  It seems like there aren't any because aioobe is saying that he'll buy me a new computer, and I doubt it's cause he just wants to spend money.  Oh well.  Keep trucking, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your loop**: `for (start = 3; start = 1000; start += 1){`
The second part of a `for( ; ; )` loop is the condition test. The loop will continue **until the second part evaluates to false**. To not create an infinite loop, change your code to:

```
for (var start = 3; start < 1000; start += 1){
```

Note: `start+=1` is equal to `start++`. If you want a compact code, you can replace `+=1` by `++`.

An overview of the three-part `for`-loop, `for(initialise; condition; increment)`:

- `initialise` - Create variables (allowed to be empty)
- `condition` - The loop will stop once this expression evaluates to false
- `increment` - This expression is executed at the end of the loop
  **Always** check against infinite loops: Make sure that the condition is able to evaluate to `false`.

Commonly made mistakes:

- A negative incremental expression in conjunction with a *is-lower-than* comparison:
  `i--` decreases the counter, so `i<100` will **always** be true (unless the variable `i` is initialized at 100)
- A positive incremental expression in conjunction with a *is-higher-than* comparison.
- A non-incrementing expression: `for(var i=0,j=0; i<100; j++)`  (`i` doesn't increase)
- A condition which is always true (such as in your case)

Comment: +1 Although I'd like to point out, that he probably should use <= instead of <

Comment: Why should it be that?  999 is the last one I'm looking at.

Comment: Then use `start < 1000` or `start <= 999`. Valid expressions for the `condition` part of the arguments are comparisons of the kind `< <= >= > == !=` **provided that** the at least one of both variables change, so that the expression is able to become `false`.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to learn and read about it properly. Your loop condition `start = 1000` will always evaluate to `true`, that's why the loop never terminates (an assignment returns the value which was assigned and any other number than `0` is evaluates to `true`).

The [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) is a great resource for learning JavaScript. Particular for this situation:

> A for loop repeats until a specified condition evaluates to false. The JavaScript for loop is similar to the Java and C for loop. A for statement looks as follows:
>
> ```
> for ([initialExpression]; [condition]; [incrementExpression])  
>    statement
> ```
>
> When a for loop executes, the following occurs:
>
> 1. The initializing expression `initialExpression`, if any, is executed. This expression usually initializes one or more loop counters, but the syntax allows an expression of any degree of complexity. This expression can also declare variables.
> 2. The `condition` expression is evaluated. If the value of `condition` is true, the loop statements execute. If the value of `condition` is false, the `for` loop terminates. If the `condition` expression is omitted entirely, the condition is assumed to be true.
> 3. The statement executes. To execute multiple statements, use a block statement (`{ ... }`) to group those statements.
> 4. The update expression `incrementExpression`, if there is one, executes, and control returns to step 2.

As the others said, it mostly comes down to try and error.... that is a good way of learning anyway.

Answer (score 1):

your conditional statement **start=1000** will always return true. You cant found such fool proof's list for this, you have to learn from these mistakes on your own.

Answer (score -1):

Uh - what did you wanted here ?

```
for (start = 3; start = 1000; start += 1)
```

do you wanted this ? ( from 3 to 1000 )

```
for (start = 3; start <= 1000; start += 1)
```

in first case you will stuck on 1000